# addClass function doesn't work as expected

Tags: jquery, css

Other effects of jQuery `toggle`, `hide` is working but `addClass` function doesn't work here. `displyanone` class is working outside, but doesn't work inside jQuery function. What is wrong here?

```js
$(document).on('click', '#menu', function() {
  if($(this).is(':checked'))
    $(this).parent().find('ul').slideDown('slow');
  else
    $(this).parent().find('ul').addClass('displaynone');  //Doesn't work
  //$(this).parent().find('ul').hide('slow'); - works. 
});
```

```css
.displaynone {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="left col20">
  <input type="checkbox" id="menu" name="menu[]" value="">
  Checkbox
  <ul class='displaynone'>
    <input type="checkbox" class="menusub" name="menusub" value="">
    Checkbox L2
  </ul>
</label>
```

Comment: Where is the `#menu` element? There isn't one in the code you've shown

Comment: This can either be due to a typo that can no longer be reproduce, or your details here are not a [mcve]. But one thing is sure - It's unclear what your asking. It implies that you're having multiple elements with the same ID too

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan. Please see updated question. Menu element is working fine. So I had avoided to decrease code length in question

Comment: Use `change` event instead of `click`

Comment: Why don't you just use `$(this).parent().find('ul').slideUp('slow');`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.slideDown()` adds an inline style property `display:block`, which overrides `display:none` from class `displaynone`. Adding the class after the inline style property was added, has no effect.

The easiest fix would be to replace `class='displaynone'` with `style='display:none'` and use `.hide()` to hide the element. In this case only inline style properties are used.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#menu', function() {
  if($(this).is(':checked'))
    $(this).parent().find('ul').slideDown('slow');
  else
    $(this).parent().find('ul').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="left col20">
  <input type="checkbox" id="menu" name="menu[]" value="">
  Checkbox
  <ul style='display:none'>
    <li>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="menusub" name="menusub" value="">
        Checkbox L2
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</label>
```